# How to retrieve an action out of a url in php

Tags: php, url, md5

I'm making a site where you can book a cabin. One of the requirements was to make a reaction system where an admin gets an e-mail with a link. If he clicks this link, the reaction will be posted on the site. I'm almost done with this, I only have one question:

http://student.waerdenborch.nl/~groep45/site/index.php?reactie=f0357a3f154bc2ffe2bff55055457068

In this link, how can i retrieve the part behind `?reactie=`?
I could only find how to retrieve more of the url, but I only want the md5.

Comment: You are getting this in GET request OR in plain text ?

Comment: Just use $_GET['action']. In your case $_GET['reactie']

Answer (score 3):

Just retrieve it by using $_GET

```
$_GET['reactie']
```

Also read this: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php